# How do I know the height from recursion tree of $T(n)=4T(n/2+2)+n$?

Tags: recurrence-relation

I already saw [this answer](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/19343/clrs-4-4-3-height-of-recursion-tree-for-tn-4tn-2-2-n). But I didn't understand totally.

So I found the solution to this equation $T(n)=4T(n/2+2)+n$.

[image]

Here is the recursion tree. But I can't compute the height as $lgn$ from this tree.

How to compute height? (Image is from [solution](https://ita.skanev.com/04/04/03.html))

Comment: The height is very close to $\log_2 n$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Suppose that $n = 2^m+4$. Then
$$
\frac{n}{2} + 2 = \frac{2^m+4}{2} + 2 = (2^{m-1} + 2) + 2 = 2^{m-1} + 4.
$$
We conclude that if $n = 2^m+4$ then the height is $m$ (or $m+1$, depending on how you count), with $T(5)$ in the leaves. This shows that for this type of $n$, the height of the recursion is $\log_2(n-4)$ (or $\log_2(n-4)+1$, depending on how you count).

For general $n$, the exact answer depends on the interpretation of $n/2$ — whether you take floor, ceiling, or anything else — but the height will still be very close to $\log_2 n$.

Comment: You mean just ignore a small constant or coefficient?

Comment: The height is very close to $\log_2 n$.